# How to turn-off a plugin in Vim temporarily?

Tags: vim, plugins

I have multiple plugins in Vim and some of them modify the default behavior of Vim. For example I use Vimacs plugin, which makes Vim behave like emacs in the insert mode alone. Sometime I want to turn off the Vimacs plugin without moving the vimacs.vim out of the plugins directory. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 41):

You can do this if you use a plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) or [Pathogen](http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), which will keep the plugin in its own directory underneath the `~/.vim/bundle/` directory.

In that case, just find out the `runtimepath` of the vimacs plugin with the following command:

```
set runtimepath?
```

Let's say it's `~/.vim/bundle/vimacs`.

Then, put this command in your `.vimrc`:

```
set runtimepath-=~/.vim/bundle/vimacs
```

To load vimacs, just comment that line out and relaunch Vim (or source your .vimrc).

Comment: Thank you! This will go well with my recent switch to Pathogen. :)

Comment: Also, you can just delete the plugin's directory, e.g. `rm -rf ~/.vim/bundle/vimacs`.

If you're using Vundle or Pathogen, reinstalling the plugin is just a `:BundleInstall` or `git submodule update` away, respectively.

Comment: Except if you have a more involved build process, like with YCM. It's not that hard, but it does take a while.

Answer (score 20):

See which variable vimacs check on start. On the begin of the script file find something Like `if exists('g:vimacs_is_loaded")...`. Then set this variable in your .vimrc or while start vim with `vim --cmd "let g:vimacs_is_loaded = 1"`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using pathogen, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261785/temporarily-disable-some-plugins-using-pathogen-in-vim#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20method%20to%20disable,pathogen_disabled%20variable%2C%20before%20starting%20pathogen.&text=Update%3A%20Another%20method%2C%20supported%20by,ends%20in%20a%20tilde%20(%7E).) gives a better answer, in my opinion. Since I have frequent need to disable snippets when using latex, also added this in my ~/.config/ranger/rc.conf:

```
map bs shell vim --cmd "let g:pathogen_blacklist = [ 'ultisnips', 'vim-snipmate' ]" %f
```

This way, whenever I want to open a file with snippets disabled, it is easy.