# Toggle sets of Vim plugins

Tags: vim, plugins, development-environment

Is there a trick or script that allows me to switch between sets of vim-plugins and -settings easily?

I use vim for very different development and writing. It can be really annoying to have certain webdevelopment-specific plugins turn up, when writing a report in LaTeX, for example.

What I'd like to see is something like [RVM](https://rvm.io).

- Have a set of "global" plugins and settings; plugins and settings that are always enabled or used.
- Per project plugins and settings; pluginss, configurations and settings that will be loaded after activating that "environment".

Comment: Vim has a runtimepath variable, which can obviously be set in the vimrc. As far as I understand it, though, you would have to restart vim for the change to take effect.

Comment: I don't mind restarting. I will know what "environment" to start up in, before I am starting vim. Having the .vim in git and switch branches would work; if not for duplicating and managing becoming a hassle.

Comment: Is the "per-project" filetype-specific? If so, you may just need your plugins to be ftplugins. Also, see `:help LocalLeader` to help separate global vs filetype plugin maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find [localvimrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441) to be useful for point number two.  It allows you to have a `.lvimrc` in your project folder with settings for that specific project.  In that file you could load your project-specific plugins by manipulating the `runtimepath` or by using pathogen/vundle/whatever.

Using this method you would configure your "global" settings and plugins as you would normally.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question IMHO. By the way, using a plugin manager could simplify this kind of stuff too. For example, with pathogen you can do something like:

```
" To disable a plugin, add it's bundle name to the following list
let g:pathogen_disabled = []

if your_condition
   call add(g:pathogen_disabled, 'myplugin')
   call add(g:pathogen_disabled, 'myplugin2')
end
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261785/temporarily-disable-some-plugins-using-pathogen-im-vim/5316897#5316897) for a good example about conditional loading. It would be very nice to see this feature implemented in pathogen.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make aliases

```
alias mvim='vim -u myvimrc'

alias ovim='gvim -U someothervimrc'
```

Ans yes you could use `runtimepath` inside the vimrc-s to setup very different configurations