# Close-vim profiler like --startuptime?

Tags: vim

There is a convenient command `vim --startuptime` that will record profiler information about vim at startup.  Is there any equivalent for *closing* vim?

My startup is fast (nearly instantaneous), but the vim gui in particular takes ~60s to close.  `mvim -u NONE` closes instantly, but that's all the information I have.  I'm looking to profile the closing stage to try to pin down the misbehaving plugin/autocmd.

Note: I thought my issue had been fixed previously (http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-slow-to-quit-td5720464.html) but it has proved resilient.

Comment: I guess you have syntastic installed, and the problem happened only for certain file type right? I had the problem too, try to disalbe the syntax checking on that certain file type, see if the problem's gone.

Comment: I have syntastic installed, but unfortunately this occurs for *all* filetypes, even (especially) blank files!  However, I'll see if disabling syntastic fixes it...

Comment: No, `let g:pathogen_disabled = ['syntastic']` reveals that syntastic is *not* at fault in this case.  But I think you've put me on the right track.  Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261785/temporarily-disable-some-plugins-using-pathogen-in-vim

Comment: You should investigate autocmds like 'VimLeave', 'VimLeavePre' etc to see what stuff might be slowing down vim before closing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, the `:profile` command. I think you need a HUGE build of Vim to have this available, though:

```
:prof[ile] start {fname}
    Start profiling, write the output in {fname} upon exit.
```

The command

```
:set verbose=20 | quit
```

will also show what Vim commands are being invoked during quit.

Comment: I have this feature, and I ran it, but it didn't record my exit time the way I expected.  It reported the total elapsed profiled time as ~1s, but the program was operating at 100% CPU for ~60-90s.  Any idea what would cause that or how to further debug?

Comment: 60s is extreme. Can you interrupt Vim in that stage with Ctrl-C? Can you `:set verbose=20 | quit` and see what's happening?

Comment: `ctrl-C` has no effect; an external kill command is needed.  You're right that it's extreme.  It seems to be writing my `.viminfo` for a long time...

Comment: Is that on a particular file system (try moving it elsewhere, cp. `:h viminfo-n`? Or do you have file marks to such in there (try clearing it once)?

Comment: The last thing I see before the long hang is `Writing viminfo file "/Users/adam/.viminfo"`.  No changes are made to the viminfo file (at least, `tail-f` shows no new lines).  It is 1.4 MB, which is large but not insane (right?).  `set viminfo='100,<50,s10,h`, so it's nowhere special.  There are file marks, but only 10.

Comment: OK, it turns out the `.viminfo` *was* insanely long.  For no obvious reason, one of my history searches was repeated ~10^5 times.  Running `:%!uniq` and writing it out has made VIM close cleanly/fast.